# Validation Appointment form

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

I'd like to ensure that the client are unable to book the same date/time for the same services that the company caters to. The codes are as follow for the fields:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Appointment Type:</div><!-- end .label-->
    <div class="input">
    <select input type="text" id="Booking" class="detail" name="ApptType" value="">
    <option value="">Appointment for</option>
    <option value="Consultation">Consultation</option>
    <option value="Photo Shoot">Photo Shoot</option>
    <option value="Dress Fitting">Dress Fitting</option>
    </select>
    </div><!-- end .input -->
    </div><!-- end .row -->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Select Date and Time:</div><!-- end .label-->
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="DateTime" class="detail" name="DateTime" value="">
    </div><!-- end .input-->
    </div><!-- end .row -->
```

I'd like a rule, where clients that book an appointment for consultation (ApptType) at (for instance) 10 Dec 2014 at 2pm, other clients aren't able to book for same date or time. I'm still a novice in this but i tried on this code after searching up codes (for my database.php):

```
 $bookingdatetime = $_POST[DateTime];
  $apptdatetime = Appt_DateTime;

$conn = dbConnect();

if (! $conn)

    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    if  ($apptdatetime != $bookingdatetime);

    return false;

} else { 

    return $sql = "INSERT INTO Appointment (Client_ID,Svc_ID,Appt_DateTime) 
VALUES ('$_POST[ClientID]','$_POST[ApptType]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST[DateTime]))."')";


mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

There is no error written in dreamweaver tho. can someone help, now i can't even store the data in my database after inserting the rules.

Comment: You would have to do a database lookup first to see if that time slot is available, if it is then write the form data to the database table, if not then show an error message.

Comment: You should not me using mysql_* queries, it is deprecated and will soon be discontinued. Use PDO instead.

Comment: @Grant I tried coding the a query but i still couldn't get this through.

Comment: You input for $DateTime should be in the format: Y-m-d H:i:s (2014-11-30 09:00:00) otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Create a Drop down menu with the time slots in this format and let the user choose, or create a method to standardise the time format.

Comment: My code below works perfectly, I tested it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the form HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Appointment Type:</div><!-- end .label-->
<div class="input">
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <select input type="text" id="Booking" class="detail" name="ApptType" value="">
    <option value="">Appointment for</option>
    <option value="Consultation">Consultation</option>
    <option value="Photo Shoot">Photo Shoot</option>
    <option value="Dress Fitting">Dress Fitting</option>
    </select>
    </div><!-- end .input -->

    <div class="label">Select Date and Time:</div><!-- end .label-->
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="DateTime" class="detail" name="DateTime" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div><!-- end .input-->
</div><!-- end .row -->
```

Here is the PDO code:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'xxx';
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $DateTime = $_POST['DateTime'];
    $DateTimeCheck = date("Y-m-d H:00:00",strtotime($DateTime));
    $ApptType = $_POST['ApptType'];

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        $sql = "SELECT DateTime FROM appointments WHERE `DateTime` = :DateTime";
        $sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql); 

        $ar_val = array(':DateTime'=>$DateTimeCheck);

        if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
            while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                $DateTimeExists = $row->DateTime;
            }
        }

    if(isset($DateTimeExists) && $DateTimeExists!=''){

            echo "Sorry that time slot is already taken";

    } else {

           $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
           $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

       $sql = "INSERT INTO appointments ( DateTime, ApptType ) VALUES ( :DateTime, :ApptType )";

           $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
           $q->execute(array(':DateTime'=>$DateTime,
             ':ApptType'=>$ApptType));

           echo "Your appointment has been created.";

           $conn = null;

    }



}
```

You will require some method to round off the timeslot to the hour or half hour or whatever. Do this in your drop down menu in the form. Otherwise one can book both the following time slots: 2014-10-10 09:09:00 & 2014-10-10 09:09:01 I.e. a timeslot 1 second later is a valid timeslot.

I added: $DateTimeCheck This rounds off the time slot to the hour and checks for the same hour time slot, so avoiding the above mentioned problem of one second intervals being booked as separate timeslots.

Comment: Hi @Grant, i am still able to book for the same time and date. The query doesn't work

Comment: My code below works perfectly, I tested it on my side. See comments in your original question above.

Comment: @A.razali I have provided the means for you to resolve this, Stack Overflow is not a forum for people to write code for you, it is a learning forum. You should learn from what I have posted to write the code you require to resolve your coding issue. Now you need to learn from what I have shown you and apply it on your side.

Comment: NB: Please also don't forget to up vote & accept my answer, as it shows how to resolve your issue.

Comment: That's why i am learning from here and applying as follows. I'd just like to know does the :____ (:DateTime, :ApptType) affect the codes largely. I'm not really familiar with PDO. is it the same logic as '$_POST[ClientID]' that i have used? @Grant

Comment: :DateTime, :ApptType catch the $_POST variables and write to those fields in the database